# Php curl for Survey Monkey API - webhook

Tags: api, curl, webhooks, surveymonkey, php-curl

I have problems configuring a webhook for "Survey Monkey". 
According to the API docs: [Survey Monkey - webhook](https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/docs?shell#webhooks) I think I have all the required arguments covered in my code and still I get the error "Invalid schema in the body provided". That mostly means there is something wrong with the POSTed JSON string data. But I can't find what is wrong...

my curl:

```
$surveyId = '123456789';   
$data_string = array(
        'name' => 'my webhook 1233456789 name',
        'event_type' => 'response_completed',
        'object_type' => 'survey',
        'object_ids' => array($surveyId),
        'subscription_url' => 'http://sometunnel.ngrok.io/job-survey-monkey-listener/completed',
    );
$data_string = json_encode($data_string);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/webhooks');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: bearer 123myaccestoken456.abc.def', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump(json_decode($server_output, true)); die;
```

The dump of the return from Survey Monkey is:

```
array (size=1)
'error' => 
    array (size=5)
       'docs' => string 'https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#error-codes' (length=54)
       'message' => string 'Invalid schema in the body provided.' (length=36)
       'id' => string '1002' (length=4)
       'name' => string 'Bad Request' (length=11)
       'http_status_code' => int 400
```

What do I do wrong here?

Comment: Body looks right, are you sure `object_ids` is a list of ids as *strings* ? Your example has hard-coded ID  `'123456789'`  as a string but maybe the value sending through in the actual code is not?

Comment: Found it, your answer started to make me think. I did send the id as an integer in the first place in my local code and that was wrong. In my example code above I added the line "$surveyId = '123456789';" to show this as question on Stack Overflow. This is actually the correct code!
The survey id's only work with string , not with integers. So thank you for giving me direction on the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [General Kandalaft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/913139/general-kandalaft)
Survey Monkey API does not accept integers for making a Curl to create a new webhook... You MUST send Id's as strings. So the above code in the question is correct.